# Change background color on button click jsp

Tags: jsp, button

I recently started learning web programming and I want to implement an application that changes the background color. There are 4 buttons on my page. I did something. But It does not work. I know, that i can use js. But it will not be right. Please, help me.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action = "apps" method="POST">
        <input  type="submit" name="red" value ="red" >



        <input  type="submit" name="blue" value ="blue" >
        <input  type="submit" name="green" value ="green" >
        <input  type="submit" name="yellow" value ="yellow" >
        <input  type="submit" name="reset" value ="reset" >
        </form>
<%
String button1Click = request.getParameter("red");
if(button1Click.equals("red")){
    <body style='background-color:#red;'>;
}

%>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the java scriptlet tag before typing html, and open it again after typing html.

```
%>
<body style='background-color: red;'>
<%
```

And you may want to remove the `action` attribute from the `<form>` since the form should be passed to the same url.

Comment: I did as you wrote, but I still have an error on startup. This "An error occurred at line: [24] in the jsp file: [/apps.jsp]
Syntax error, insert "super ( ) ;" to complete BlockStatements"

Comment: Try running my code on your own, please.

Comment: there's no way this code `seems fine` he has html and javascript inside a java if statement!

Comment: you cannot change the html/css of the page with java like this unless you involve javascript. Your scriptlet isn't even formatted correctly. And even if it was, it would produce two body tags which is illegal html.

Comment: @Owl_Livi try now

Comment: @Roshana_Pitigala, Okay, it changes color, but not by pressing a button.

Comment: Does not work. What should the full code look like?

Comment: The rest of your code is fine. Input `type='submit'` should give you a button

Comment: @owl_livi Clear browser cache and try again

Comment: This is all not working. So I decided to ask how the full code should look.

Comment: Accept the answer for this question and ask a new question. :)

Comment: New question on the site? I can add here answer. It will be ok to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @owl_livi if you are posting the whole code to know what has gone wrong, post it as a new question. Don't append anything to this one unless an answer to the above specific question.

Comment: [Okay, I did it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112066/change-bg-color-jsp)