# Change bg color jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, background-color

[Previously asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106241/change-background-color-on-button-click-jsp)  about this.  When I run the code - I get an error in the expression:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception
occurred processing JSP page [/apps.jsp] at line [15]

12:         <input  type="button" name="red" value ="red" >
13: <%
14: String button1Click = request.getParameter("red");
15: if(button1Click.equals("red")){
16:     %>
17: <body style='background-color: red;'>
18: <%
```

How can I fix it? All code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action = "apps" method="POST">
            <input  type="button" name="red" value ="red" >
    <%
    String button1Click = request.getParameter("red");
    if(button1Click.equals("red")){
        %>
    <body style='background-color: red;'>
    <%
    }

    %>

            <input  type="submit" name="blue" value ="blue" >
            <input  type="submit" name="green" value ="green" >
            <input  type="submit" name="yellow" value ="yellow" >
            <input  type="submit" name="reset" value ="reset" >
            </form>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Don't know what exception you're getting, but your current approach is sure to generate malformed HTML.

Comment: Maybe. According to the assignment, I need to have 4 buttons on the page and they will change color. And I can't use js. And I'm trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of a `NullPointerException`. Try

```
if(button1Click != null && button1Click.equals("red"))
```

Replace `<body>` tag after `</header>` tag with your whole java code.

Comment: An application to run, but does not change the background by pressing a button

Comment: I found a mistake. Thanks

Comment: why did you ask her to create a new question for the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

you are using java code in your jsp page. Jave code always execute first. So that your color not get changed on button click